# Share same socket in WPF application

Tags: wpf, sockets, share

I have a lot of screen in my WPF application that use a socket.
Actually all screen create a new Socket to the same server but its not the best idea.
What is the good design to share a single socket in the application?

thanks

Comment: This is a bit too open-ended of a question for this site. If you're having a specific problem, post some code so that we can help you with it.

Comment: My application is Client (WPF) - Server (WPF). All screen create a connection to server by socket. But with 10 screen open i have 10 sockets between the same client-server. If I want create only one socket for the application and share the connection by all screen what is the pattern/technology to use ? thanks

Comment: Will all 10 screen's be the same application ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your 10 screens are from one application

The class that you create that communicates with the Server can be using the Singleton pattern
http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static

This means that accross the whole application this class will be the same class you initialized at first, this class will open the connection to the server and send/receive data.

Just be sure to make use of Sequential identifiers when sending and receiving to know which form sent data and must receive data.

Also make sure that you are using some sort of thread save Queuing system to send data.

Hope this helps

Comment: No need for a singleton - just create a single object and pass a reference to it to all screens that need to use it. It'll make dependencies between your code more clear and makes it easier to test.